# Check if email is taken through AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am currently making a registration form. I wanna include a feature that checks if a entered email address is taken. But, I also need to check if the email is in the right format. This is the JS code that I came up with:

```
$('#email').keyup(function() {
    var email = $("email").val();
    setTimeout(function() {
        var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,10})+$/;
        if (!regex.test($("#email").val())) {
            $("#email").css("border", "1px solid #ff0033");
            $(".bubblemail").fadeIn('slow');
            $(".wrongmail").fadeIn('slow');
            $('#postEmail').attr('disabled', true);
        } else {
            $("#email").css("border", "1px solid #232323");
            $(".wrongmail").fadeOut('slow');
            $(".bubblemail").fadeOut('slow');
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/ch-public/default/assets/scripts/checkRegister.php",
                data: "type=email&input=" + $("email").val(),
                success: function(result) {
                    if (result == 'free') {
                        $("#email").css("border", "1px solid #232323");
                        $(".takenmail").fadeOut('slow');
                        $(".bubblemail").fadeOut('slow');
                    } else if (result == 'taken') {
                        $("#email").css("border", "1px solid #ff0033");
                        $(".bubblemail").fadeIn('slow');
                        $(".takenmail").fadeIn('slow');
                        $('#postEmail').attr('disabled', true);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }, 0);
});
```

The PHP code on the other end:

```
if ($_GET['type'] === 'email')
{
    $query = Database::$conn->prepare('SELECT mail FROM users WHERE mail = :input');
    $query->execute(array(':input' => $_POST['input']));
    $number = $query->fetchColumn();
    if ($number > 0)
    {
        echo 'taken';
    }
        else
    {
        echo 'free';
    }
} 
elseif ($_POST['type'] === 'username')
{
    $query = Database::$conn->prepare('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :input');
    $query->execute(array(':input' => $_POST['input']));
    $number = $query->fetchColumn();
    if ($number > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
        else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I did the type thingie so that I wont have to create 2 separate files for the email and the password.

I've made sure that the database connection works. But the thing doesnt work. No response in the console. So how can I fix this?

Comment: A side note, validation should be done on the backend, or both back and front. It shouldn't just be on the front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better design would be to post the whole form and validate it at once.

First we create a script that validates the user.

```
// users/validator.php
$errors = array();
$cxn = Database::$conn;

function validate_presence($attr){
  global $errors;
  if (empty($_POST[$attr])) { 
    $errors[$attr] = "$attr is required.";
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function validate_uniqueness($attr){
  global $errors;
  $val = $_POST[$attr]:
  if (validate_presence($val)) { 
    $stmt = $cxn.prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE $attr = :attr");
    $result = $query->execute(array(':attr' => $val));
    if ($result->fetchColumn() === 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      $errors[$attr] = "$attr taken";
      return false;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

validate_uniqueness("username");
validate_uniqueness("email");

return $errors;
```

We then create a script that we post to with ajax:

```
// users/validate.php
$errors = require('validator.php');
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array("errors" => $errors));
```

You can also reuse the validator:

```
// users/create.php
$errors = require('validator.php');

if (empty($errors)){
   // @todo insert user into database.
}
```

You would call this from your javascript like so:

```
var validated = $.post('/users/validate.php', data: { $( "#my_form" ).serialize() });
validated.success(function(data){
  if (data[:errors].length) {
    // todo display errors...
  } else {
   // wehoo!
  }
});
```

Comment: This was coded to be a simple example, it's not intended as a copy-paste replacement. Some assembly required!

Answer (score 1):

In the AJAX data parameter you are not sending data properly.Your current code is

```
data: "type=email&input=" + $("email").val(),
```

should be `$("#email);`

Even in     `var email = $("email").val();` no class/id selector is present.

Comment: Thanks for noticing, but the problem is not yet solved. Can't it be that the fault is somewhere in the PHP?

Comment: could you do a var_dump($_POST) in PHP a see what it shows up?